# Woocommerce+wpml product images

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm running WP with Woocommerce and WMPL plugins. It works perfect for translation exept a detail:

When I translate a product from english (main language) to french, using WPML translation managment plugin, everthing is ok but the images I add to the english version is not shown on french version. Do I miss something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this might be a bug in WPML, which we already have on our todo list to fix. We should have a nice new release for WooCommerce Multilingual this week. I'll write about it in our blog and invite people for beta testing.

http://wpml.org/blog/

Answer (score 0):

I think that i had also a similar problem and i was able to fix it with the WPML Media Translation

**Settings > Drop down to media translation**

check:

- **Translate existing media in all languages**
- **Duplicate existing media for translated content**
- **Duplicate the featured images for translated content**
- And then **start**